# Вывод товара в Magento

Tags: cms, magento

Как вывести определенные товары(т.е. те, которые необходимо,так сказать, продавать в первую очередь) в начало списка товаров в категории?

Comment: Добавить атрибут и после ордер бай по нему

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант добавить атрибут, например featured тип yes/no и для категории и для послойной навигации(категории с активнымит фильтрами) в слое ..app/design/frontend/theme/package/layout/catalog.xml установить дефолтную сортировку, пример:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager" template="page/html/pager_bottom.phtml"/>
                <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>desc</string></action>
                <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>featured</string></action>
                <action method="setSortBy"><param>featured</param></action>
            </block>    
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Вот на что следуют обратить внимание, задается тип сортировки DESC/ASC и атрибут (в данном примере featured) по которому сортировать

```
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>desc</string></action>
<action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>featured</string></action>
<action method="setSortBy"><param>featured</param></action>
```

Аналогично добавить в секцию  и в catalogsearch.xml если нужно